# How to show post title in content editor in backend?

Tags: wp-query, query, query-posts, editor, wp-editor

Is this possible? I am trying to use a pre-defined template for my contents. To do that, I use something like this:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'custom_editor_content' );
function custom_editor_content( $content ) {

     $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=> 15,   
        'orderby'  => array( 
                'ID' => 'DESC' ,
            ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $query_contents=Array();

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        array_push($query_contents,Array(
            "id"=>get_the_ID(),
            "title"=>get_the_title(),
            "url"=>get_permalink(),
        ));

    }
    $content = '



    '.get_the_title( $id ).'


    ';
   return $content;
}
```

But I can't get the post, somehow. Does someone know how to do this? If I put the while statement into $content, it shows the whole query in the editor and that's not what I want of course.

**All I want to do is to fetch the post title and show it in the content editor (after posting or before, that wouldn't matter)**

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the title of the post you're creating, and add it to the content? The [`default_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/default_content/) filter appears to be meant for the initial content in the Write Post form.

Comment: Yes, I am trying that indeed. I want to fetch the title of the post I am creating... is that even possible?

Comment: Probably,  but I suspect you'll need to involve some Javascript,  because PHP won't have access to the data until you've at least saved the post initially. Until you save it, the data (including the title) is not in the database.

Comment: But what if I'd have a variable that fetches the post title AFTER I create the post. Is that possible with solely PHP? I don't need to see the title until it's created anyway.

Comment: Yes, you can get the post's title with `get_the_title( $post_id )` after the post is saved. But in that case, I don't think you want the `default_content` filter. I think you're looking instead for [`the_editor_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_editor_content/), which filters the post's content prior to putting it into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

`$id` isn't set anywhere in your code snippet. `get_the_title( null );` returns an empty string. If you want the title of a post, you'll need to set `$id` to a proper post ID.

(Also, `$args`) is unset in the code you've posted, and I don't see anywhere that you use `query_contents` either.)

Comment: Hi there, sorry, I missed to add a chunk of my code. I edited it now. Could you help me out? I did set a get_the_ID(). Should I put that in a variable too?